# Does Springboot @RefreshScope work with records

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am building an application with java 21 and Springboot. I have added the Springcloud config and actuator dependencies. I was wondering if I can use Java records with to refresh the configuration like I do with classes?

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "remote.file")
@RefreshScope
public record Fileproperties( String nfsnameing path  ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you still can do that with java 21

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "remote.file")
@RefreshScope
public record FileProperties(String path) { }
```

Comment: it give the following error: Annotated with @ConstructorBinding but defined as Spring component. The application also does not start : and logs out Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter. Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class

Comment: can you change Component to "@Configuration"

Comment: It still provides the same error

Comment: are using a     @ConstructorBinding for the constructor ?  check this out https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot#immutable-configurationproperties-binding

Comment: I have not added the @constructor binding it. isn't it the default behaviour of java record?